# PHP - Facebook Marketing API won't initiate object

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting started with the Facebook Marketing API through PHP, I've got the SDK installed in the composer.json file, I've got an long-life access token etc and I'm pretty sure I have everything mentioned in the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/quickstart) however it's still not working. Whenever I fire up the page nothing occurs, just a blank page.

This is the code: (I've got the app secret, access token and app ID tokens set already but didn't post them here):

```
<?php

// Add to header of your file
use FacebookAds\Api;

// Initialize a new Session and instantiate an Api object
Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $_SESSION[$access_token]);

// Add to header of your file
use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;

// Add after Api::init()
$me = new AdUser('me');
$my_adaccount = $me->getAdAccounts()->current();

print_r($my_adaccount->getData());

?>
```